# 3D track not tracking rotation?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, tracking

I've 3D tracked a scene and the positional tracking is amazing my model is staying exactly where it should be, but then my camera rotates, and for whatever reason instead of the model rotating it just slides sideways. I've set the y-axis, scale, floor, origin and wall and I have at least 20 trackers. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: There is not enough information on the question to help you out. We know absolutely nothing about the tracked scene or what kind of motion you are dealing with, nor do we know anything about the 3D scene, oe what kind of tracking or motion solve you are using or the error average of the trackers, etc, etc. I'm sure what you are experiencing is quite easy to fix, but without your help no one can really help you.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

If anyone sees this and knows what I did wrong I would appreciate it if you post, but for now, I just manually keyframes my model to stay in the right position so to avoid wasting peoples time I'm going to mark this as an answer.
Have a nice day!

I guess I'm waiting two days to be able to mark my own post as an answer.... Why?